# Why is my ajax call only handling part of the data i am sending to my server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to use Ajax to upvote a post. Iin addition to sending upvote data, I want to send the ID of the post so that I can eventually use findOneAndModify from mongoose to target that specific post and upvote by 1. For some reason, I can use ajax to upvote a specific post, but sending the object ID back to the server isnt working.

here is my JADE client code

```
            each post in posts
                .media.white.paddingBoxForPost
                    .media-left.media-middle
                        a.removeTextDeco(href=post.link, target='_blank')
                            img.media-object(src=post.img, alt='facebook logo')

                    .media-body
                        a.removeTextDeco(href=post.link, target='_blank')
                            div#mainTitlePost.media-heading.postTitleFont= post.title
                            div#mainShortDesc.descriptionFont= post.description
                        form(method="post")
                            label(for='upvote')
                                .form-group
                                    select#mainPostId.postIdentity.hidePostId.form-control(name='upvote')
                                        option= post._id
                        button.upvoteClick.btn.btn-lg.btnColor(type='submit')
                                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-fire 3
                        button.btn.btn-lg.btnColor(type='submit')
                            span.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment
```

And here is my Ajax call

```
$(function () {

    $(".upvoteClick").click(function () {

        var postID = {postID: $('.postIdentity').val()};
        var upvoteIncrement = {upvote: 1};

        // alert(postID);
        // console.log(postID);


        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: upvoteIncrement, postID,
            dataType: 'json',
            url:"http://localhost:9000/api/upvote"
        }).success(function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            // console.log('Process success');

        })
    })
});
```

And finally here is my server code

```
router.post('/upvote', function (req, res, next) {

var data = req.body.upvote;
var query= {title: "Will this work"};
var update = {$inc: {upvote: data}};
var options = {new: true};
var Upvote = mongoose.model('Upvote', schema);
var mongoPostId = req.body.postID;


console.log(mongoPostId);
console.log(data);

Upvote.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, posts) {
        if (err){
            console.log('got an error in your DB');
        res.sendStatus(200);
        }});
    // .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
    // .catch(next);

console.log('process SHOULD be done');
// console.log(data);



});
```

in console.log(mongoPostId) I keep getting undefined. However the problem is somewhere with my ajax call because I can't seem to send the postID variable along with the upvoteIncrement variable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ajax()` config is missing object notation for the data value, so `postID` is getting set in the `ajax()` config object instead of the data object. Try this instead:

```
data: { upvoteIncrement, postID },
```

Also, your upvote value will be at `upvoteIncrement` and not just `upvote` like you currently have in your server-side code.